# Como melhorar esse código

Tags: java, json, string

Há alguns dias pedi ajuda aqui no SO para fazer parse de JSON em Java e consegui o que queria, porém, tive que fazer uma "gambiarra" por desconhecer um modo melhor.

Está funcionando, mas tenho certeza que o código pode ser melhorado.

meu JSON é o seguinte:

```
"weather": [ 
         { 
           "id": 800, 
           "main": "Clear", 
           "description": "tempo claro", 
           "icon": "01n" }
          ], 
"main": { 
           "temp": 16.29, 
           "pressure": 1020, 
           "humidity": 77, 
           "temp_min": 16.29
        },
```

minha saída é

```
O tempo está: tempo claro
A temperatura neste momento é de 16.29º
```

e o código para gerar minha saída foi o seguinte

```
JSONObject condicao = obj.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);      

escritor.println("O tempo está: " + condicao.getString("description"));                        
String n = obj.getString("main");                      
String t [] = n.split(Pattern.quote (","));                      
String x = t[0];                      
escritor.println("A temperatura neste momento é de " + x.substring(8,13) + "º");
```

Como vocês podem ver eu não consegui isolar os campos da categoria `main` já que eles estavam todos em uma `String` só.

Assim criei várias strings auxiliares para splitar, separar o que eu desejava exibir e então cortar os caracteres que eu não desejava que fosse printados.

Vocês poderiam me dizer como fazer isso de maneira mais prática?

Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma vez que tem um JSON o ideal será navegar em toda a informação através dos métodos do parser de JSON ao invés de utilizar regexs e/ou splits.

**Utilizando org.json**

A forma mais direta de obter a temperatura, que é neste caso a propriedade `temp` do seu JSON, seria:

- Aceder primeiro ao objeto `main` com `getJSONObject`
- Sobre esse objeto aceder agora ao campo `temp` com `getDouble`

Aplicando ao seu código:

```
JSONObject condicao = obj.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);
System.out.println("O tempo está: " + condicao.getString("description"));
JSONObject mainObj = obj.getJSONObject("main"); //como JSONObject e não String
System.out.println("A temperatura neste momento é de " + mainObj.getDouble("temp") + "º");
```

**Utilizando twitter4j**

Embora a lógica a aplicar para esta biblioteca seja a mesma, não existe de facto o método `getDouble` que obtém o valor diretamente como `Double`.

Pode em vez disso utilizar o método `get` que devolve um `Object` e que no caso do valor a ser interpretado ser um numero decimal este `object` irá ser um `Double`, tendo praticamente o mesmo efeito que o `getDouble` do *org.json*.

Assim apenas a ultima linha necessita de ser diferente:

```
System.out.println("A temperatura neste momento é de " + mainObj.get("temp") + "º");
```

Comment: Exato. Basicamente o amigo não sabia que é possível acessar um objeto aninhado através do método `getJSONObject`.

Comment: Obrigado, Isaac. O código passado por você apresentou problema com o `getDouble` que, segundo o NetBeans não existe na classe, mas resolvi com o `mainObj.get("temp") ` ou `mainObj.getString("temp") `. Falo isto para que você possa editar a resposta e assim ajudar mais pessoas com a mesma dúvida. P.S. minha biblioteca de JSON utilizada é a `Twitter4j` já que também estou implementando integração com a API da rede social na aplicação

Comment: @Max De nada. Tinha assumido que estivesse a utilizar *org.json* e por isso não coincidiu/funcionou com a biblioteca que estava a utilizar. Obrigado por avisar, que assim já atualizei a resposta para contemplar ambas as soluções.